# How to determine where an IP returned by NSLOOKUP is coming from

Tags: windows, domain-name-system

We have a Windows 2012 AD environment with two domain controllers.  We have a mac workstation which has an IP of 10.8.214.30.  It resolves fine and pings fine, but when you do an nslookup you get the following:

```
C:\Windows\system32>nslookup MAC5 DC1
Server:  DC1.ny.ald.com
Address:  10.10.0.1

Name:    MAC5.ny.ald.com
Addresses:  10.8.215.45
          10.8.214.30
```

Note that it returns two IP's.  I am unable to determine where there is an entry for 10.8.215.45.  I even created an entry for a non-existent host called DUMMY and assigned that IP to it -

```
C:\Windows\system32>nslookup dummy DC1
Server:  DC1.ny.ald.com
Address:  10.10.0.1

Name:    dummy.ny.ald.com
Address:  10.8.215.45
```

Likewise -

```
C:\Windows\system32>nslookup 10.8.215.45 DC1
Server:  DC1.ny.ald.com
Address:  10.10.0.1

Name:    dummy.ny.ald.com
Address:  10.8.215.45
```

As you can see it resolves properly.  Why does the MAC5 host still include this IP?  Is there any way to do a search of DNS in DNS Manager to determine whether an incorrect entry exists in one of the many sub-folders?

--------------------------------------------------------per THECLEANER suggestion --------
Using the debug option, I get -
I got the following using the debug option - 
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 1, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  response, auth. answer, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 1,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        1.0.10.10.in-addr.arpa, type = PTR, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    ->  1.0.10.10.in-addr.arpa
        name = DC1.ny.ald.com
        ttl = 1200 (20 mins)

------------
Server:  DC1.ny.ald.com
Address:  10.10.0.1

------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 2, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  response, auth. answer, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 2,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        MAC5.ny.ald.com, type = A, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    ->  MAC5.ny.ald.com
        internet address = 10.8.214.30
        ttl = 1200 (20 mins)
    ->  MAC5.ny.ald.com
        internet address = 10.8.215.45
        ttl = 1200 (20 mins)

------------
------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 3, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  response, auth. answer, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 1,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        MAC5.ny.ald.com, type = AAAA, class = IN
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ->  ny.ald.com
        ttl = 3600 (1 hour)
        primary name server = DC1.ny.ald.com
        responsible mail addr = admin.ny.ald.com
        serial  = 765192
        refresh = 900 (15 mins)
        retry   = 600 (10 mins)
        expire  = 86400 (1 day)
        default TTL = 3600 (1 hour)

------------
Name:    MAC5.ny.ald.com
Addresses:  10.8.214.30
          10.8.215.45

Comment: nslookup has a `set debug` and a `set d2` option if you type nslookup and then hit enter first.  This will give you the full DNS lookup query information.

Comment: Sorry if its a stupid question, but does your MAC also have a wireless nic? Regarding your DNS server, I was gonna say you could export your tables to text, but it looks like TheCleaner has a better answer.

Comment: Thx.  I edited the original post to add the results of debug.  Still doesn't shed any additional light though...

Answer (score 2):

No "searching" is necessary. There are two A records for `MAC5.ny.ald.com` in the `ny.ald.com` forward lookup zone. The DNS server is returning both of them to `nslookup`.

Jump into DNS Management, navigate to that forward lookup zone, and delete the "A" record that you don't want to be in there. (Likely the device has a wired and wireless NIC and has had both IP addresses registered in DNS.)

Comment: I should have mentioned that I've already done that portion of troubleshooting.  There is no additional record referencing that IP nor that hostname in the forward lookup.  Ditto for reverse.